# result from 3 tables into on multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have three tables like `feeds`, `posts`, `images`. I want to retrieve all posts (from post table)  along with their `feed logo`,`feed url` (from feeds table) and image `urls` (from image table) into one multidimensional array.

Suppose I wrote three functions -- one is to retrieve posts, the other is for feed info, and the last is to retrieve post image urls -- and those functions return the result in an array. How can I combine the three arrays in one json response?

The response should be like:

```
- post {
         [
         -title =,
         -id =,
         -body =,
         - images {
                url(1): ={};
               ....
               ...
                url(n): ={} ;
               },
            - feed {
                  -id:
                  logo_url:
                  .....
                  }
],
```

Comment: the issue here is that, the second and third arrays depends on the first array i.e. the array returns the feeds details gets feed id from post result also image array takes post id from post array to retrieve image urls from images table

Answer (score 0):

Like Toby points out, you want to use `json_encode`.

Comment: this is my json function function echoRespnse($status_code, $response) {
    $app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
    // Http response code
    $app->status($status_code);

    // setting response content type to json
    $app->contentType('application/json');

    echo json_encode($response);
}